# MySQL table create taking way too long

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that creates 70 empty tables. However, it's taking nearly 30+ seconds to create them.

What is causing it to take this long? How can I speed the process up?

Comment: you'll need to give us a bit more information than that if we're to help you =) Is the database server local? How big are the tables (i.e. how many columns, each)? Have you measured how long each "create" is taking to determine if one is taking the majority of the time? What storage engine are you using for these tables? The more information you can give, the better the help we can give =)

Comment: @Rob- Yes, the database server is local (I'm on a VPS). The tables range in size from 2 columns to 15 columns. Running this script on my old server (shared hosting),  it would create all of them in approximately 5 seconds. I have not measured how long each "create" is taking. The storage engine is MyISAM.

Comment: have you tried directly connect using mysql client?

Comment: Just creating one table (5 columns), took 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

An increase in the amount of memory PHP can access might speed this up. You really aren't giving enough information to help. The code would be really useful.